# Referring to someone's country of ancestry in an informal way?

Tags: british-english

What is a good way to refer to a person's country of ancestry?

Im going pretty much everywhere in Europe this year and in Australia we have so many Australians of European ancestry.

For example a person born in Australia to parents who emigrated from Greece.

How could I express that I will be visiting the country of their ethnic background?

Comment: Very carefully.  Many terms that are used to identify ethnic origin are considered derogatory by at least some members of the groups involved.

Comment: *I understand your family are Greek. I'm going there this summer*.

Comment: Yes Im thinking that I should just be saying "Hey I'm going to ____" ... But would be interested to know if there is a word that can be used like this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll be visiting the land of your ancestors

?

Answer (score 0):

Just say

> I am going to visit your grandparents' country

also

- **native land**
- **homeland**

Comment: Some people might take offense at the implication that the country where they were born (Australia, in this case) is not their "homeland".

Comment: @HotLicks I believe he means `your grandparents' homeland`

Comment: It depends so much of the culture. I also wanted to suggest 'Fatherland' but I read it has some Nazi implications. In any case, 'native land' may be  more neutral in this meaning

Comment: @HotLicks no, in the above case the person born in Australia tells the phrase to parents born in Greece, 'a person born in Australia to parents who emigrated from Greece'. So 'homeland' is exactly the word.

Comment: That makes no sense.  The OP said "a person born in Australia", so how is he telling the phrase to "parents born in Greece"?

Comment: It's the example situation from the question.

Comment: Yes lol I thought of the Fatherland as well but yep.. Now I am thinking that Motherland could be a good word, for someone proud of their background I wouldn't think that it sounds like it seems to be saying they are any less Australian.

Comment: 'fatherland' and 'motherland' are interesting. They are (obviously) English words, and used in English for the country/place where a person comes from but never for English speaking people. Which implies that they are only used to translate similar terms from non-English languages. In English culture, an English speaking person from, say, Devonshire or Iowa or Queensland never refer to that place as 'fatherland' or 'motherland', but probably simply 'where I grew up' or if  noun is preferred, 'my birthplace'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word **roots** fits this context.

> I'll be going to Greece this summer, because that's where my parent's roots are.

---

> [Roots](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roots) 
> 6.
>   a. often roots The condition of being settled and of belonging to a particular place or society: *Our roots in this town go back a long way*.
>   b. roots The state of having or establishing an indigenous relationship with or a personal affinity for a particular culture, society, or environment: *music with unmistakable African roots.*